# while loop adds a char instead of addition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm looping through the results of a dictionary and the first key is "TC", the next key would be "TC2", and so on.  The while statement on the code below loop to TC1 then to TC12.  It's adding a char instead of doing addition on i.  How can I add 1 to each TC through the loop.

example: TC1, TC2, TC3, etc.

```
NSString *key = @"TC";

dict = [resp objectForKey:key];
NSString* cNum = [dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_NUM"];
NSString* usrn = [dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_POS_NAME"];
NSLog( @"First for Cashier Num=%@, Cashier Name=%@", cNum, usrn);

if (cNum  != IDNUM) {

   // key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", key, i];
    NSLog(@"KEY after if %@", key);
    dict = [resp objectForKey:key];
    cNum = [dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_NUM"];
    usrn = [dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_POS_NAME"];
            NSLog(@"c1= %@ , %@", cNum, usrn);

    while (cNum  != NULL) {
        int i = 0;
        NSLog(@"Key on While %@", key);
        i++;


        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", key, i];
        dict = [resp objectForKey:key];
        cNum = [dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_NUM"];
        usrn = [dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_POS_NAME"];


        NSLog(@"c2= %@ , %@", cNum, usrn);

        NSLog(@"KEY %@", key);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the value of the original "root" key around so that you can append a new number to it on each iteration. Then instead of using "key" in your stringWithFormat call, use "rootKey".

Comment: Duh. Thank's for making me realize my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As JoshL mentioned do this:

```
NSString *rootKey = @"TC";
....

key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", rootKey, i];
```